# How to unit test that a MutableSharedFlow<T>(replay=0) has emitted a value?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I'm not able to figure out how to test that a `SharedFlow` with `replay=0` emitted a value.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.Test

class ShowcaseTest {

    @Test
    fun testIntSharedFlowFlow() {
        val intSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

        runBlocking {
            intSharedFlow.emit(1)
        }
        
        // Does not work as there is no buffer because MutableSharedFlow(replay=0)
        assert(intSharedFlow.replayCache.first() == 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to test with replay=1, you can try to emit before "observing/collecting", so before the job started.

```
@Test
fun testIntSharedFlowFlow() = runBlockingTest{
    val _intSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val intSharedFlow: SharedFlow = _intSharedFlow
    val testResults = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val job = launch {
        intSharedFlow.toList(testResults)
    }
    _intSharedFlow.emit(5) 
    
    assertEquals(1, testResults.size)
    assertEquals(5, testResults.first())
    job.cancel()
}
```

Don't forget to cancel the job, otherwhise the sharedFlow will continue collecting, and the test will give you an error or even loop forever.

Comment: Important here is the use of `runBlockingTest` and not `runBlocking`

Answer (score 7):

One solution would be to use the `Deferred` object returned by `async`

```kotlin
@Test
fun `test shared flow with deferred`() = runBlockingTest {
    val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = 0)

    val deferred = async {
        sharedFlow.first()
    }

    sharedFlow.emit(1)
   
    assertEquals(1, deferred.await())
}
```

**Note**: you must use `runBlockingTest` so `async` body is executed immediately so there is no chance that `emit(1)` is executed before `first()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [tryEmit()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/) instead and verify the returned result

**UPDATE:**

Consider using [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine)
For ex:

```
sharedFlow.test {
    sharedFlow.emit(1)
    assertEquals(expected = 1, expectItem())
    cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()

}
```

Comment: Not possible, the test targets a ViewModel of an Android Fragment that requires to use emit, otherwise production code does not work at all.

Comment: `emit()` internally uses `tryEmit()`. You can check the implementation, but it's analog to suspending until `tryEmit()` returns true I believe.
So you could do the same in your `runBlocking()` I suppose. I'm not sure if there is a better approach currently

Comment: @VíctorAlbertos updated my response with one of my recent findings

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it soon :)

Comment: @RóbertNagy how to verify no more emit are done? Or this is not possible to do it with this library? I know there's the `awaitComplete()` but it throws an exception, do I have to catch this exception to verify no more emit are there?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS not sure how would you approach that. So `SharedFlows` are hot observables, which means they will "never complete" (That's stated in the docs as well). 

With streams you're basically testing data in a point of time. To test that no more emits are done, you are basically applying "during eternity no more emit is done", so `awaitComplete()` will naturally time out. Alternatively you could test if the `Flow` have completed, but that's again a hot observable, which will not complete by design

Comment: I've used `expectNoEvents()` in the end, what do you think about this method? I found in the documentation

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS you could use together with `cancelAndConsumeRemainingEvents() expectNoEvents()`. If you are not interested on the events, you could simply do `cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()`

Answer (score 6):

runBlockingTest is deprecated since 1.6.0, use runTest instead. [the migration link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md)

```
@Test
fun `test shared flow with deferred`() = runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
    val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = 0)

    val deferred = async {
        sharedFlow.first()
    }

    sharedFlow.emit(1)
   
    assertEquals(1, deferred.await())
}
```

Comment: This works. Make sure to add `UnconfinedTestDispatcher()`.